# Update LG G2 to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, lg-g2

I read about the update for LGD802 (G2) to Android 5, but if I run the software update by phone by LG Mobile Support Tool I did not find any available update. Now my phone is update at version 4.4.2.
Am I wrong or it should update to 5?

Answer (score 0):

As written in this [article](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/06/03/lg-g2-android-5-1-lollipop-update/) the update to android 5.0.2 for LG G2 introduced some bugs and issues. Probably they stopped the roll-out and will release android 5.1 directly to the phones that didn't receive 5.0.2. Keep in mind that you may have to wait a little once the roll-out officially begins, because the servers have a limited capability. Your phone should automatically notify it once the update is ready. If it takes too much time or you read on the net that G2 won't eventually get an update, consider updating it by yourself.